# Regex to capture digits after pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't seem to find the issue with this code:

```js
const regex = "/tel:\+61(\d+)/g";
const subscriberNumber = senderAddress.match(regex);
```

For input text, `senderAddress` = `tel:+619123456789` the `subscriberNumber` is null.

What's causing it to return null?

Comment: basically, the goal is to remove the "tel:+(area_code)"

Comment: `const regex = "/tel:\+61(\d+)/g";` is not a regex, and doesn't contain any backslashes, either - it's equivalent to `/tel:+61` etc. If you want a regex, use `new RegExp` (and double-escape the backslashes) or, even better, use a regex literal `const regex = /tel:\+61(\d+)/` (drop the global flag)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't escaped the + in 61. + is used as a concatenation operator too.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think the parentheses around \d+ are necessary.